# My Java code keeps adding duplicates to a text file

Tags: java, file

I'm writing some code in Java that will be able to read and write text files for a stock portfolio project. I'm able to read and write, but when I try to read a file twice in the same runner class, it at first outputs the content and then it outputs twice the content, instead of outputting the same content twice.

The pertinent classes are (and please excuse their length):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class FileModifier {
    private String path;
    private int numOfLines;
    private ArrayList<String[]> arr;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private BufferedWriter bw;

    public FileModifier(String p){
        path = p;
        numOfLines = 0;
        arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    }

    public void read(){
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = line.split("\t\t");
                arr.add(row);
                numOfLines++;
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    public void write(){
        try{
            read();
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
            String content = "";
            for (String[] line : arr) {
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                    content += (line[i] + "\t\t");
                }
                content += "\r";
            }
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getContents(){
        read();
        return arr;
    }

    public int getNumberOfLines(){
        read();
        return numOfLines;
    }

    public String[] getLine(int n){
        read();
        return arr.get(n);
    }

    public void addLine(int n, String[] newLine){
        read();
        arr.set(n, newLine);
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract public class Account {
    private FileModifier file;

    public Account(String historyPath){
        file = new FileModifier(historyPath);
    }

    abstract public double getBalance();

    public void addToHistory(String[] newLine){
        ArrayList<String[]> contents = file.getContents();
        contents.add(newLine);
        file.write();
    }

    public String getHistory(){
        String history = "";
        for(String[] line: file.getContents()){
            for(String part: line){
                history += part + "\t\t";
            }
            history += "\n";
        }
        return history;
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class StockAccount extends Account{
    private ArrayList<String[]> arr;
    private DecimalFormat df;
    private SimpleDateFormat da;
    private int numOfShares;
    private double portfolioValue;
    private double balance;
    private FileModifier portfolio;

    public StockAccount(String p){
        super("C:\\stock_transaction_history.txt");
        portfolio = new FileModifier(p);
        numOfShares = portfolio.getNumberOfLines();
        arr = portfolio.getContents();
        portfolioValue = 10000;
        balance = 10000;
        df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        da = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    public String displayPortfolio(){
        String output = "";
        String[] temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfShares; i++){
            temp = arr.get(i);
            for(int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++){
                output += temp[k];
                output += "\t\t";
            }
            if(i < numOfShares - 1)
                output += "\r";
        }
        return output;
    }

    public double getStockPrice(String symbol){
        for(String[] line: arr){
            if(line[0].equals(symbol))
                return Double.parseDouble(line[2]);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int getAmountOwned(String symbol){
        for(String[] line: arr){
            if(line[0].equals(symbol))
                return Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public double getStockValue(String symbol){
        int amt = getAmountOwned(symbol);
        double price = getStockPrice(symbol);
        if(amt == -1 || price == -1){
            return -1;
        }
        return amt * price;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        double value = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size()/2; i++){
            value += getStockValue(arr.get(i)[0]);
        }
        balance = Double.parseDouble(df.format(portfolioValue - value));
        return balance;
    }

}
```

Now, when I try to do

```
StockAccount sa = new StockAccount("C:\\Result.txt");
System.out.println(sa.getHistory());
System.out.println();
System.out.println(sa.getHistory());
```

I get

```
Event       Symbol      Owned       Price       Value       Time        
Buy     GOOG        10      $577.49     $5774.90        09:40:07        
Buy     MSFT        100     $30.00      $3000.00        13:37:00        


Event       Symbol      Owned       Price       Value       Time        
Buy     GOOG        10      $577.49     $5774.90        09:40:07        
Buy     MSFT        100     $30.00      $3000.00        13:37:00        
Event       Symbol      Owned       Price       Value       Time        
Buy     GOOG        10      $577.49     $5774.90        09:40:07        
Buy     MSFT        100     $30.00      $3000.00        13:37:00
```

I've read my code over but I don't see anywhere that files would be duplicated. Is there just something about file reading that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1):

This is when you should be going into detective mode with your debugger. Why is it exactly *twice* the actual content the *second* time? In what variable is the content stored? When is it appended to? Could you be doing that twice by accident? On purpose?

> Take a good hard look at how you're interacting with FileModifier#arr.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the way you have implemented your `public void read()`. Your `getHistory()` invokes `file.getContents()` which call read(). Read adds element to your `ArrayList<String[]> arr`. `getContents()` then returns `arr`. Note that `arr` will keep growing every time you call `getHistory`. If you call it once, you get the expected result, but if you call it more than once you start to see the anomaly in your code.

I don't know what tool you are using, but [here is a good tutorial on debugging with eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)  or if you like video tutorials, [knock yourself out.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUGinutrSzN-ALgaL0mSyPDHi3VhUCcuV)